# How to resize multiple canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, xaml, canvas

I want to resize multiple shapes at same time.Here is my xaml code. It has 2 canvas called g6 and g10 but in real project i got nearly 100 canvas. Any solution?

```
<Canvas
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="svg2"
    Width="612"
    Height="800">
    <Canvas
        x:Name="g4"
        RenderTransform="1.3702001,0,0,1.4522231,268.12186,265.31238">
        <Canvas x:Name="g6">
            <Path
                x:Name="path8"
                Data="F1 M-153.219,-37.369C-153.219,-37.369 -153.168,-36.483 -153.579,-36.491 -153.99,-36.5 -162.189,-58.998 -172.418,-57.948 -172.419,-57.948 -163.557,-61.389 -153.219,-37.369L-153.219,-37.369z"
                Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
                Stroke="#FF000000"
                StrokeMiterLimit="4"
                StrokeThickness="0.172" />
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="g10">
            <Path
                x:Name="path12"
                Data="F1 M-151.46,-38.783C-151.46,-38.783 -151.734,-37.933 -152.117,-38.073 -152.5,-38.212 -152.06,-61.988 -162.059,-64.269 -162.059,-64.269 -152.48,-64.673 -151.46,-38.783z"
                Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
                Stroke="#FF000000"
                StrokeMiterLimit="4"
                StrokeThickness="0.172" />
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Have you done any research at all?  What you you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current information -

You can create `Width` and `Height` properties in your `ViewModel`(or CodeBehind or whatever object you are setting as `DataContext` of your `Window`/usercontrol) and bind `Width` and `Height` of your each `Canvas` to them; Changing these properties in code will resize all the canvas in your xaml.

In case you don't want to add bindings to each canvas you can create a global style for `Canvas`([without `x:Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms745683%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#styling_targettype)), which will automatically be applied to each `Canvas`; but you will have to be careful in putting this style in correct place, in the current xaml you have provided adding this `style` to your top most Canvas's resources will make sense.

something like this -

```
<Canvas xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        x:Name="svg2" Width="612" Height="800" >
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding GlobalWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding GlobalHeight}" />
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <Canvas x:Name="g4" ... />
    <Canvas x:Name="g6" ... />
    <Canvas x:Name="g10" ... />
</Canvas>
```

As a sidenote, I would suggest you to not rely on converted XAML as it is; try and refactor it to use appropriate conrols/panels, extract relevant parts into usercontrols, use styles/triggers etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Canvas> Collection = RootControl.Chidren.ofType<Canvas>();
foreach(Canvas c in Collection)
{
    c.Height = NewHeight;
    c.Width = NewWidth;
}
```

Comment: what you mean with MyShape? I want to resize all my canvas.

Comment: i dont want to resize them one by one.

Comment: What do you mean @hellzone? What ever you do it will change the properties one by one. That is pretty much all code is executed, line by line. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Viewbox that will contain all your canvas... Give us more information about your project.

Comment: i just convert SVG file to XAML. The thing is my XAML file now has 100 canvas. I want to resize all of them at runtime.